# Vbscript How to find what is give date format?

Tags: vba, datetime, vbscript

I want to know what is the format of given date in vbscript?
Example

If the date is 10/08/2015 I want to check whether which format it its?

dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy

I check so many function is vbs nothing fit for my requirement

Comment: You haven't found a function because it is impossible to determine the date format using only the information `10/08/2015`.  It can be either. What is the underlying problem you need the date format for?

Comment: If you have a set of date strings all in the same format then, if the set is large enough and sufficiently random, you can with high probability infer the format used. If you have variables of subtype `Date`, the date-values themselves don't *have* format since format is a property of string representations of the date values as opposed to a property of the underlying values. Note that you *can* check what format Windows is using when it displays the date along the bottom bar of the screen.

Comment: You can refer to the code on [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/676540-visual-basic-applications-check-if-date-valid-certain-format-dd-mm-yyyy.html) page to check for any specific format. the code there check if any date is of format `dd.mm.yyyy` you can use that logic to check for other format.

Answer (score 0):

The following function might be useful in some situations. It can distinguish between dd/mm/yyyy and mm/dd/yyyy when possible and tells you when not. It does no error checking so would give misleading results if the string is anything other than a valid date in one of those two formats:

```
Function FormatUsed(dateString)
    Dim parts, first, second

    parts = Split(dateString, "/")
    first = CInt(parts(0))
    second = CInt(parts(1))

    If first > 12 Then
        FormatUsed = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    ElseIf second > 12 Then
        FormatUsed = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Else
        FormatUsed = "??/??/yyyy"
    End If
End Function
```